# What are the varnas (castes) of Lord Hanuman and Jambavan?

Tags: hanuman, caste-system, varna, vanaras

Hanuman was the child of Añjanā and Kesari. Both Anjana and Kesari belonged [to the  Vanara clan.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanara)

Is the Varna System mentioned in our scriptures applicable only to human beings or is it applicable to Vanaras as well?

In any case, what is the varna (caste) of Hanuman?

Likewise, what is the varna of Jambavan (father of Krishna's third most important wife Jambavathi)?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Ha ha, I am in research of a good, perfect, counter-less and valid example for inter-caste marriage in Hindu scriptures, which I didn't find.

Comment: :-) "which I didn't find." and what does that tell you.

Comment: It only applies to human beings, not other races.

Comment: @moonstar2001 It tells that discouraging Inter-caste marriages is invalid.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Did Jambavati belongs to human race?

Comment: @hanugm No, she didn't.

Comment: there is no good, perfect, counter-less and valid valid example for inter-caste marriage and this means that inter-caste is valid and must be encouraged?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Then how  lord Krishna accepted her as wife (If she is not human and from other race and Krishna was human in Dwapara)?

Comment: @moonstar2001 If there was an example, then such marriages can be encouraged, else it is superstition.

Comment: what logical construct is this?

Comment: @moonstar2001 If there was an example(from rishis, munis, gods.. ), it is not a sin, So it shouldn't be discouraged.

Comment: @hanugm You are allowed to marry people belonging to non-human races, like Devas, Gandharvas, Vanaras, etc.  It's only inter-caste marriages that have restrictions on them.

Comment: but you yourself say you have found no such example.

Comment: More importantly, even if you did find such examples, are we capable of the same feats as rishis, munis, gods? We take their examples when flouting dharma. Not in emulating their tapas and charity.

Comment: @moonstar2001 The issue in finding such example is people are playing with words varna and caste. Some are saying that both are same, which is not correct, because there are too many castes and only 4 varnas.  So caste is not same as Varna, If we stick to this, then there were lot of inter-caste marriages.

Comment: @hanugm Caste and Varna are the same.  Castes have different sub-castes/communities within them though.  Hindu scripture imposes restrictions concerning marriage between different castes, not about marriage between different sub-castes of the same castes.

Comment: so you want to prove inter-varna marriage is not acceptable?

Comment: Among the 16 combinations,  only 6 are forbidden. https://imarriages.com/d/images/advice/how-kundali-matching-works-varna-chart.png

Apart from this, I want to show that, there is nothing to do with caste, only Varna matters but not caste.

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri On this site, both varna and caste are considered same. You can post about it on [meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com), if you want them to be treated differently.

Comment: Varnashram belongs to the descendants of Manu, or Manav. Not other species.