# Who is Matanga rushi?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, caste-system, varnashrama, matangi

What are the names of Matanga rushi's father and mother? Were children of Matanga  rushi Brahmins? how did Matanga rushi change his caste? Was Jambavanta a Chandala?

Comment: What is the connection between Jambavanta and Matanga Rushi?

Comment: Many says matanga rushi is chandala and jambavanta is chandala .

Comment: So both being Chandal is the only connection? Or they are relatives too?

Comment: Some say that jambavanta belong to matanga rushi family

Comment: Oh okay ........

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/what-are-the-varnas-castes-of-lord-hanuman-and-jambavan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A story of Matanga attaining Brahmanahood is present in [Skanda Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skanda_Purana).

His father's name is Sugati. The names of his mother and biological father are not mentioned.

> There was an eminent Brahmana named **Sugati** in Dvapara Yuga. He had
> control over his sense-organs. He was truthful always and engaged in
> the study of the Vedas. Matanga was his son who was excessively
> terrible ever since his childhood.
>
> [[Chapter 60: Matangesvara, Section 2: Caturasiti-Linga-Mahatmya,Book 5: Avantyakhanda, Skanda Purana]](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.20764/page/n221/mode/2up)

After realizing that he is a Chandala, Matanga performs *intensive* penance and attains Brahmanahood. He may be unmarried. Scriptures do not contain any statement related to his marriage and offspring. Finally, he reaches Brahma Loka.

A brief story about Matanga is as follows

> As a child Matanga hit a young one of a donkey. The mother-donkey
> consoled her child telling that Matanga was born of a rape of his
> mother by a barber and was a Candala. When Matanga heard it, **he
> determined to be a Brahmana by performing penance. Indra dissuaded him
> and at last sent him to Mahakalavana where, by the sight of this
> Linga, he became a Brahmana and went to Brahmaloka.** Hence the Linga
> came to be known as Matangesvara.

Although there is a [similar story](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a027.htm) in Mahabharata, some details of the story are different, including the ending. He does not become Brahman in the end.

Comment: Do chanadala are aryans

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud What do you mean by Aryan?

Comment: Dvaparayuga? Is it the dvapara before Ramji took an avatar or after that? And the story means that he was the son of the wife of Sugati by a barber?

Comment: @Archit Yeah, after Rama only. And yes, the son of Sugati's wife by the barber.

Comment: Accha if he was after Rama then how could he have made Shabari wait for Rama?

Comment: @Archit Please share the verse of Mathanga asking Sabari to wait. Is it his disciples?

Comment: Accha see: [Valmiki Ramayana Aranya Kanda Sarga 73](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga73/aranya_73_frame.htm) and [Valmiki Ramayana Aranya Kanda Sarga 74](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga74/aranya_74_frame.htm) - verse 15-16. Okay so as per this they’re saying the disciples of Matanga told her to wait not Matanga personally. Sorry. But ya the ashram was his and he had cursed Bali and all. That story you can find in the Kishkindha Kanda. But the basic essence is Matanga has to come before Rama.

Comment: @Archit ha. In the Mahabharata story, he became a flying being and the time is not mentioned.