# What is the story of Vasista changing his caste through penance?

Tags: scripture, caste-system, vashishta

It is almost impossible for an individual to change her caste in her lifetime. It will take at least five generations to change the caste.

> ‘Caste becomes elevated **during the fifth or the seventh generation**;
> similarly after five or seven generations one acquires that caste of
> which he has followed the occupations.’
>
> [Yājñavalkya (1.96)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201772.html)

For an individual Jiva, it will take several births to change her caste. The following words of Indra to Matanga can confirm this

> From the order of brute life one attains to the status of humanity. If
> born as human being, he is sure to take birth as a Pukkasa or a
> Chandala. Verily, one having taken birth in that sinful order of
> existence, viz., Pukkasa, one, O Matanga, has to wander in it for a
> very long time. Passing a period of one thousand years in that order,
> one attains next to the status of a Sudra. In the Sudra order, again,
> one has to wander for a long time. After thirty thousand years one
> acquire the status of a Vaisya. There, in that order, one has to pass
> a very long period. After a time that is sixty times longer than what
> has been stated as the period of Sudra existence, one becomes a person
> of the fighting order. In the Kshatriya order one has to pass a very
> long time. After a time that is measured by multiplying the period
> last referred to by sixty, one becomes born as a fallen Brahmana. In
> this order one has to wander for a long period. After a time measured
> by multiplying the period last named by two hundred, one becomes born
> in the race of such a Brahmana as lives by the profession of arms.
> There, in that order, one has to wander for a long period. After a
> time measured by multiplying the period last named by three hundred,
> one takes birth in the race of a Brahmana that is given to the
> recitation of the Gayatri and other sacred Mantras. There, in that
> order, one has to wander for a long period. After a time measured by
> multiplying the period last named by four hundred, one takes birth in
> the race of such a Brahmana as is conversant with the entire Vedas and
> the scriptures, There, in that order, one has to wander for a very
> long period. While wandering in that status of existence, joy and
> grief, desire and aversion, vanity and evil speech, seek to enter into
> him and make a wretch of him. If he succeeds in subjugating those
> foes, he then attains a high end. If, on the other hand, those enemies
> succeed in subjugating him, he falls down from that high status like a
> person falling down on the ground from the high top of a palmyra tree.
>
> [[Section 28, Anusasanika Parva, Anusasana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a028.htm)

But there are some exceptions to the words by Indra due to some reasons. The exceptions are given in the following verse

> ‘Viśvāmitra, Mātaṅga, Vaśiṣṭha, Nārada and others became elevated by
> special penances, not by birth.’
>
> [Śukranīti (4.4, 80-81)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201772.html)

The story of Viśvāmitra changing his Kshetriya caste to the Brahmin caste is mentioned in several scriptures. Mahabharatha contains the story around [this](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01179.htm) chapter in Chaitraratha Parva of Adi Parva. Gandharva says the story to Arjuna.

The [story of Mathanga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44121/661) rushi changing his caste from chandala to Brahmin is mentioned in Skanda Purana.

But I never came across the story of Vaśiṣṭha changing his caste during his lifetime. Which scripture mentions the story of Vaśiṣṭha changing his caste and what is the story?

Comment: most probably it's his second birth [from apsara Urvashi]... otherwise in his first birth he was mental son of Lord Brahma..