# What is the varna of Jambavan?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, caste-system, varnashrama

Many people in South India say that Jambavan is a dalit. 
 Is it true?
What do Ramayana and other scriptures say?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/what-are-the-varnas-castes-of-lord-hanuman-and-jambavan

Comment: Answer did not giveb

Comment: But your question will be closed as a duplicate one.

Comment: Jambavanta is a bear he doesn’t have any Varna. Varna applies to humans mostly.

Comment: I don’t agree. Sugriva was a monkey yet a king.

Comment: In most cases where Jambavan is described, he is presented as a ksatrya. Especially when he des describes his own prowesses on the shore of the ocean and explaining why he can’t swim to Lanka anymore. Those were prowesses of a ksatrya.